# GRPC Auth - How to make SSL/TLS Cert Available to Client

Tags: ssl, grpc

I'm trying to create a GRPC service to authenticate users. The back end server will be written in Go and the front end will be in Javascript. The connection between client and server must be secure, so I will use SSL/TLS on the server side.

My question has to do with the GRPC client API. When creating a GRPC client to make the request, I need to specify a credentials object:

`var ssl_creds = grpc.credentials.createSsl(root_certs);
var stub = new helloworld.Greeter('myservice.example.com', ssl_creds);`

There are a number of different credentials objects I can supply, but they all seem to require having the public key for the server present on the client side. How do I get the public key from the server to the client to create the credentials object? Do I have to do any sort of verification myself to ensure that the cert is trusted?

For libraries used to make REST HTTP requests, this step seemingly happens in the background, as I do not have to specify the key. Often you can supply the key as an optional parameter, which is only necessary when the SSL cert is not verified by some certificate authority. How are these libraries (e.g. jQuery or Python's requests library) fetching the necessary public key and performing verification? Is there similar functionality in the GRPC library which I can use for this purpose?